# Cannot find symbol method requestPermissisons

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write a method where I get the user's current location. If I try to run:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissisons(this,new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},0);
```

I get an error saying:

> cannot find symbol method
>   requestPermissisons(MainActivity,String[],int)

I made sure I imported ActivityCompat at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a **TYPO**

its **`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`** not `ActivityCompat.requestPermissisons`

Try this

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},0);
```

Answer (score 3):

requestPermissisons should be requestPermissions